# Request working on Postman but receiving 403 on Node JS

Tags: node.js, axios, postman

I'm trying to make a request on NodeJS, but i'm always receiving 403 Error, so I tried to execute the same request on Postman and it was Ok. Postman generates a code snippet so I can execute the same code that was executed by postman, but I continue receiving the same error.

[image]

Node Error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403
You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;mob&#46;internetbanking&#46;caixa&#46;gov&#46;br&#47;sinbc&#47;nb&#47;loginLightNovo&#63;" on this server.<P>\n
```

Anyone have idea about why it can happens?

Edit: Node JS Code:

```
var axios = require('axios')

var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://mob.internetbanking.caixa.gov.br/sinbc/nb/loginLightNovo=',
  headers: {
    Cookie: 'JSESSIONID="tQzZfGXt6KOpwB7RGlBS6Oi+.nodelx126:mobnbcinter01e-lx126"; _abck=DB08BBA73AF120AF37B21F522BFAFB1D~-1~YAAQRtsAyat/3fB6AQAAAKkEfgYYwpytAUktZYSmnJXsbC+5ORcbttfG8nYsGH+o3Mz5FsowJGrSkY17ctQ1DaFcH1frR/gVf6+r+okuUnqwTBv+kZ5Of7eHX+GrJygJIY80AeZLj/ZMTKL6nX9ley3jSDIcQg3+dCF//nbPC1kutG9EhlFOdVusquURQMbCy/J8BOSSMdCGv/Go4c7pdS82odvkoJk0dMzQuYAjgGdWln8Txn+rIA9HTx/OjCJ4pKBSch8H4Il4elmtGajXlovBiiDBiw5jN77Pb+XxxbYHe6ja4g4RpwU9dkWZBd5rILZ+6ZFZfIrUlxKNPJN4FC34BstPeBRRal7UytWMIWFy4I/PRDox3f7MzRDAkVmMJFZQmOJxHuaH~-1~-1~-1; bm_sz=6042D22A2B04B9A8DE73C59C015B0108~YAAQRtsAyax/3fB6AQAAAKkEfgxNYLSdlTwJNd9hH5QH9uZ8v/dJSr6CNH0/s+e/L8hgejaH1EgbwP7xF0HrhE4DHfTGyjEsogEQv0sp71QXUlIiS61KhLq/TV9l3V0XBgnzcsOIMdSmCDIHb9Bocy3xGiwaHXq3nyMxaepYJ8GppwAIfI/cUiQxwoUcj4bxcAAKvv1CVsBj7b1rzw4c/wYkyhPgaYI0yI8TbWIO9Un+eUCfGOaB1UNQuBciTc8qBO1LThCOxlQK9lUofmIQjwiRztfGKr7yOAGfS0ksaDnheLFIzg==~4605493~3621425; ak_bmsc=0F89D62B2D17FC8C3AFADFF8D9DEAC60~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQVdsAyZfzWvh6AQAApYc1fgyFtYbEUMPe+dkKRV6FG0zQ01tmlJZLCw3VXEgOuxn5hT+zE6taQOAE6StO+h8saigGWcT/AN+QKiJ/4FPxZKZ4iidjF9L08lXrzT8va8J97whdaKM0t+HTnF/BAD19Sh80TDeD+OCcWgEdUMHI2DVpNlps5var1XPwMsMrJWaHa7OnGE9hnfXbkKy5YZlO3YpvFWdVxmelID588r+gXjy6EdZ7druK1TxSC5FS9gIHmN85lu3FWUwKs0ey2XCuTNU4Rvj5uwxF7bd6/mj4cAxvrsc3mD5PEDoHlD/ZtiFPinFvolzzYj2vhB60HKxOoo1wi47950iuhzwkCNVODXdmbgIDS9m+n5nFWiUIaxMXJqvm7Oe6IpP0hgQ=; akaalb_mob_alb=~op=mob_cef:alb01|~rv=69~m=alb01:0|~os=b303c53633196a06063b67f5470ae0ff~id=b3f50dad6abb43664c38f1bc231ffb82; bJ1spGC0yyDM=v1GgPygxCc3C6'
  }
}

axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Comment: are you sending the cookie header on your nodejs request?

Comment: yeah.. i'm sending exactly how postman generated the snippet in the right side of the image

Comment: can you share your nodejs request code?

Comment: sure.. i edited the question

Comment: from where did you get that cookie? Did you get from a login action?

Comment: Postman generated that cookie.. i don't know how

Comment: I think it's related with cors problem, but i dont know how to fix

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between NodeJs script vs Postman is User-Agent generated in HTTP Header.

Solution: you should add User-Agent into your NodeJs script. For example: Add following string into the HTTP header

`'User-Agent': 'Node/12.14.1'`